# Effective usage of a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, nested-loops

I understand that a trailer value is entered in my loop to end the program.  The purpose of my program is to enter a kid's name and then their grades.  When you are done with a single kid you enter -1 to end that part of the program.  After you are done with one kid the program should ask you to enter another kids name.  The trailer value "Done" works, but when I enter a random kids name when it asks it says the name isn't defined, and it won't run the rest of the program.  Help?

```
#By: Christian Braverman 01/02/13

#Variables

TotalNum_A = 0
TotalNum_B = 0
TotalNum_C = 0
TotalNum_D = 0
TotalNum_F = 0
studentname = 0
Done = 0
grade = 0

#Loop
studentname = input("Enter student name ")
while studentname != Done :                    
    studentname = input ("Enter student name ")
    grade = input("Enter a Grade ")
    while grade != -1:
        grade = input("Enter a Grade: ")

        if grade >=90 :
            print "A!"
            TotalNum_A = TotalNum_A + 1


        if grade >=80 and grade <90:
            print "B!"
            TotalNum_B = TotalNum_B + 1


        if grade >=70 and grade <80:
            print "C"
            TotalNum_C = TotalNum_C + 1


        if grade >=60 and grade <70:
            print "D"
            TotalNum_D = TotalNum_D + 1


        if grade <=59:
            print "F :("
            TotalNum_F = TotalNum_F + 1
    grade = input("Enter a Grade: ")

#Printing Totals

print ("You received " + str(TotalNum_A) + " A's.")

print ("You recieved " + str(TotalNum_B) + " B's.")

print ("You recieved " + str(TotalNum_C) + " C's.")

print ("You recieved " + str(TotalNum_D) + " D's.")

print ("You recieved " + str(TotalNum_F) + " F's.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `raw_input` instead of `input`- that way, it will take a string instead of requiring the input to be an already existing variable. Then replace

```
while studentname != Done:
```

with

```
while studentname != "Done":
```

Note that as of now there is no reason to even ask for students' names, since as of now your program doesn't do anything with them.

Comment: I know the names are useless, but this is for my Computer Science class and I have to have the names there.  Thanks though!

Comment: do I replace all of the input statements with raw_input statements?

Comment: @ChristianBraverman: Not the `grade = input("Enter a Grade: ")` ones- that or you can replace them with `int(input("Enter a Grade: "))`. The idea is that `input` (in Python 2.X, not Python 3) is effectively reading Python code from the user (like a number or a variable name) while `raw_input` is reading a string.

Comment: I added the int(input("Enter a Grade: ")) to the studentname = input ("Enter a student name") ones.  a.k.a the first ones. Also I put  quotation marks around the -1 and the done values.  It doesn't work.  The problem with your comment before is that all of my input statements are regular input = ("Enter a grade") statements. can you elaborate on which ones to change?

Comment: Don't put quotation marks around -1 if you put `int(input("Enter a Grade: "))`- once you do that, the result of `int(input("Enter a Grade: "))` would be `-1` the number, not `"-1"` the string! I never told you to do so!